# Levels of a Factor into a New List (R)

Tags: r, for-loop

I currently have a factor `adj_factor` that has just under a thousand levels, each containing a different adjective . I created this factor from a data frame that contained only one column, an adjective, using `dplyr::pull(adjs_df, adjs) -> adj_list`. I would like to turn that factor into a list so that each element is more easily accessible in a method or for loop I aim to write, any advice?

Comment: Do you need `as.list(adj_list)` ?

Comment: Yes it's not an actual R list that's just how I named it

Answer (score 0):

```
#Create sample factor
Factor <- as.factor(c("a", "b", "c", "a", "a", "b"))

#Levels returns the different levels of a factor as a vector of strings
#Only usable with factors
levels(Factor)

#Unique shows all the different values in any vector (character, numeric...)
unique(Factor)
```